# Joomla: Links in custom components

Tags: html, joomla, joomla1.5

I am developing my first Joomla component and am having trouble understanding how to insert a link to edit a item in my component.

Let's say I wanted to list an item and add a link to edit it. I'm not sure if I can just write a link with normal HTML, although that doesn't make so much sense could how could you make sure the link is correct if you make any changes or use SEF urls.

So basically what is the format for creating a link to a different task in your component?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever making links in your component remember to always pass it through the JRoute Joomla function:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_foo&view=man&task=chu');
```

This will ensure that when you turn on SEF urls for Joomla that the URLs will be converted to  their SEF counterparts. Please note that your component URLs will not be converted if you do not develop a router.php file for your component.

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  Is there a way to automatically/dynamically put in the component into a link?

Comment: I write the link but I leave out the `?option=com_foo` part and the router puts it in for me. Or perhaps, how do I dynamically find the name of the component currently being used so I can write something like `?option=$component`.

Comment: I can't see how/why you would need to assign a component name dynamically. If a component is currently being used then it's the component's code that is running and not your code therefore you cannot define the link at all as this is another code base. If your component is running then another component cannot also be running.